# Optimize alternating formatting in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I have an application that runs a specific piece of `VBA` code that I need to speed up.

I've looked around for solutions, but it's so specific I couldn't find anything. I'm changing the format of rows 4-3000 or so for visibility. This takes a long time on an old computer, which is where this process is usually run. Do you guys have any ideas for how to optimize it?

```
For i = Range(startCell).Row To Range(endCell).Row Step 2

    Rows(i).Interior.color = RGB(50, 50, 50) 'Grey background
    Rows(i).Font.color = RGB(0, 240, 255) 'Cyan text
    Rows(i + 1).Interior.color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 'Black background
    Rows(i + 1).Font.color = RGB(240, 255, 0) 'Yellow text

Next
```

Comment: Check out [codereview.se] next time you have working code you want optimized.

Comment: Where and how are `startCell` and `endCell` assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a little procedure like this in a code module:

```
Public Sub ToggleWaitMode(Optional ByVal wait As Boolean = True)
    With Excel.Application

        .Calculation = IIf(wait, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .Cursor = IIf(wait, xlWait, xlDefault)
        .StatusBar = IIf(wait, "Please wait...", False)

        .DisplayAlerts = Not wait
        .ScreenUpdating = Not wait

    End With

End Sub
```

Then modify your code to call it:

```
ToggleWaitMode
'<your code>
ToggleWaitMode False
```

That *should* speed things up a bit... or at least give the user some feedback while the loop is running.

---

Another (perhaps better) no-code alternative is to use conditional formats (using a formula looking something like `=(MOD(ROW(),2)=0)`.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I didn't log in to my account to comment on it, but this worked fantastically. Better late than never